# If I write all zeroes or ones to a hard disk, does that effectively and securely wipe it?

Tags: hard-drive, security

If I wanted to completely and securely wipe a hard drive, could I simply write all ones or zeroes (or even just random zeroes and ones) over the entire disk to clean it? It'd probably take forever, but is my theory correct?

Comment: No! Magnetic hard drives have "memory". Forensic tools will still be able to recover (part of) the files.

Comment: Depends on you paranoia level, "average joe computer guy" a few write cycles should be more than fine, CIA/NSA/MI6/etc. thermite :)

Comment: @Dennis: That is just not true. See my comment on RedGrittyBrick's answer.

Comment: You may be interested in the conclusions of [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/how-can-i-reliably-erase-all-information-on-a-hard-drive) on this one, particularly the top voted answer.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/how-to-recover-securely-deleted-data is what I got for answers when I asked

Comment: @DanielAndersson: I stand corrected. Very interesting link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should suffice. There is a theory that you need to do this multiple times because of variations in tracking, however the threat countered by this seems largely theoretical.

You may find it easier to use a drill or a very large hammer.

Comment: I do agree however that unless you are giving the machine away, selling it, or donating it to a charity, physical destruction is best. Besides, HD magnets make great toys and refrigerator magnets.

Comment: http://www.springerlink.com/content/408263ql11460147/ - a reference to that the threat is _purely_ theoretical. Not a single application of this technique has been documented as successful, even after just a single zero overwrite. See also http://www.h-online.com/newsticker/news/item/Secure-deletion-a-single-overwrite-will-do-it-739699.html for a summary. As data densities increase immensely, it gets even more unfeasible by the year. And the equipment that is supposed to be used is not cheap, to say the least.

Comment: @EBGreen, what tools?

Comment: You are correct. When you put the question to me I went back and did some research. My statements were based on older articles that have since been clearly refuted. I retract my previous statements.

Comment: Physical destruction doesn't mean that data recovery is impossible.  (Unless you have all the pieces...).  It's possible to reconstruct magnetic media, if you have quite a bit of patience..  (Impractical in most cases, but it's been done before...)

Comment: @Benjamin: You might enjoy http://www.ontrackdatarecovery.co.uk/data-recovery-for-bang-goes-the-theory/

Answer (score 1):

> Once upon a time there was a man named Peter Gutmann who suggested
>   that with the use of an electron microscope you might be able to
>   figure out what was once written to a part of a hard drive that had
>   been overwritten. That lead people to come up with policies like “you
>   have to overwrite 7 times before it is safe to dispose of.” However,
>   despite all the assurances I’ve heard that it can be done, nobody
>   knows anyone that has actually done it. A couple years back I took a
>   forensic class with Mike Murr from the SANS institute and he was
>   talking about this very thing.Everyone knows someone that has done it,
>   but nobody has done it themself.

As a general guide line, wiping the drive 3 times is the maximum wipe count that I will use.  Beyond that is overkill, unless your are dealing with extremely sensitive data.

Any data recovered after 2 wipes, is probably impossible.  3 or 5, would make it virtually impossible.

Comment: I don't bother w/ 2nd or 3rd passes.  Quoting part of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1224851/401839): [University of California San Diego (UCSD) Center for Magnetic Recording Research (CMRR): G.F. Hughes: Secure Erase, as archived on July 5, 2013...](http://web.archive.org/web/20130705073109/http://cmrr.ucsd.edu:80/people/Hughes/SecureErase.shtml) notes, “Many commercial software packages are available using some variation of DoD 5220, some going to as many as 35 overwrite passes. Unfortunately the multiple overwrite approach is not very much more effective than a single overwrite”...